# After Flutter 3.0 update fluttertoast library start showing this error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'exports')

Tags: flutter, flutter-3.10

After upgrading flutter to latest stable channel fluttertoast library start showing this error and when i call methode showToast it show below error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'exports')
```

assets/packages/fluttertoast/assets/toastify.js 14:48  
assets/packages/fluttertoast/assets/toastify.js 14:90  
ReferenceError: Toastify is not defined

Comment: it may help you https://github.com/ponnamkarthik/FlutterToast/issues/254#issuecomment-749109746

Comment: you should upgrade to the latest fluttertoast version (^8.2.1 afaik)

Comment: I got the same error. do you fix this issue yet?

Answer (score 3):

Early fix by shivbo96. his commit hash is 3362fbe84cde30bd68875f1e04c214c72b054fd9
link https://github.com/ponnamkarthik/FlutterToast/commit/3362fbe84cde30bd68875f1e04c214c72b054fd9
[image]